# C#: Conversion (Recognition) a MATH formula from a TextBox

Tags: c#, function, math, textbox

I have a problem. In my application I want to use a function ( let say `f(x)`, where `x` is the variable ) which is typed in a textbox, for example `sin(x) + x*x - 5`.

What I want is C# to recognize this function as `Math.Sin(x) + x*x - 5`, in other words to know that `x` is the variable.

I have for x some 2000 datas, let say `xi`, where `i = 2000`, so all I want is `f(xi)` values, for all the `x` datas, where `f` is the function from the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is an expression parser - i.e. a piece of code that converts the expression string in the text box in something that can be executed (a syntax tree typically).

If you google "math expression parser c#" you'll find various stuff - from products like [this](http://www.bestcode.com/html/bcparser_net.html)  to simple examples like [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/patricklundin/MathExpParser12062005062213AM/MathExpParser.aspx).

Comment: I saw the example with .NET Math expression Parser, but when I want to intrdouce:

using info.lundin.Math;


it questions me if I am missing some using directive or an assembly refference?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to download MathparserCode.zip, that will contain the assembly you need. WARNING: I did not try it, it is just a link I found searching the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you, or your user, to define the variable names ahead of time?

e.g. let the user know they can use "y", "x" or "n" as variable names, but not anything else OR have the user define the variables within the program before trying to parse the formula?  That'll make it a lot easier to recognize them within the text and handle them accordingly.

In terms of actually parsing the expression, consider converting it to "Reverse polish notation".  Here's an example program: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5875/C-Expression-Parser-using-RPN

Comment: Thanks for your responses, Mimo and Dylan. In my case, the variable which appear in the formula is x. So, is a singulary variable.